# Website using drag and drop

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I am student and new to .net and website development. i have given website as project in asp.net in which one can drag and drop HTML control and generate simple static website. now when user drag and drop specific HTml control then its copy or you can say clone will be placed sothat user can drag and drop same HTML control multiple time
 can anyone help me?

Technology Asp.net with C# (.net 4.5)

Comment: I believe that (contrary to the current answers) this is a question about using Visual Studio's visual designer to create a simple website, rather than a page that has support for drag and drop interaction. However, the OP needs to clarify the question.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) is Jquery Draggable !  It's easy and useful with a little script !

```
     <script>
$(function() {
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
});
</script>
```

This is [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hmJCQ/1/) for it !

Answer (score 2):

You can use just jquery and not c# or any server side technology.Using [JqueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/):

This is complete sample:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually i want to make website that through which any user can create simple static website like blog. how can i do this with draggable.  can you give me some link to refer